# Control the ranking of my sites on Google

Tags: seo, search-engines, google-search-console, google-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best ways to increase a site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google)

I have two sites that I both control and have hooked up to Google Webmaster Tools as different sites. My problem is that one of the sites (Site A) was created as a preparation for the other site (Site B).

Although I want Site A to still exist (even on Google), I would like to have Site B score better in search engines.

Is there anything I can do implicit or explicit to make Google (and preferable also other search engine) prefer Site B's content over Site A's?

Answer (score 0):

Is the content the same on both site A and site B, if so I would try and get more unique content on to site A. There's nothing you can do in Webmaster Tools of Google and Bing to tell them to start ranking a different site of yours better than the other. Your only options are to keep adding good content to site A and get back links. Or redirect site B to A

Comment: No, not same content. Also, redirection is not a solution. I want both sites. Site A is an investigative site in preparation of Site B

Comment: Well bottom line is unless you delete one domain or forward it or stop publishing content on it and focus on domain B Google's going to keep ranking it. And as you are aware no one knows why really. Get lots of quality back links and keep posting content to site B. That's pretty much it